# Nop Commerce builtin database not working

Tags: asp.net, database, nopcommerce

I have installed nopcommerce 3.7 , a few days ago. Now when I try to login via any account it doesn't work. It returns to main page with no user logged in .

Comment: I think you download solution with code. You have to build Nop.Web. After building full source it works I think. Or try to debug the code why dont you logged in. Then ask question here.

Comment: I'm using no source installation

Comment: @NaveedKhan before start you need cleen solution and rebuild solution.